# Generated code from xsd won't compile

Tags: maven, xsd, jaxb, xjc, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I'm using this maven plugin:

```
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
```

and an xsd that I have been provided with. The code generation process appears to work ok, I end up with an ObjectFactory and one other class (GoldenSource.java) representing the object defined in the xsd. All looks good.

However, later in my build process when attempting to build the generated class I get compilation errors, namely:

```
cannot find symbol
```

I check the particular symbol it is complaining about and it is there, as a public static inner class in GoldenSource

I've tried with xjc from java 1.7.0_45 and 1.8.0_51, and different jaxb plugins and nothing makes any difference.

In the same project I have another xsd that generates classes as expected. One difference between the two is primarily that the xsd that works is a mere 148 lines long whereas the one that doesn't is 7026 lines long. Is there a restriction on size somewhere?

Another difference is that the xsd that works does not contain any nested complexTypes whereas the one that doesn't build contains loads. Is there a restriction on this somewhere?

Comment: Have yout tried creating your class via the xjc command line tool as well?   $JAVA_HOME/bin/xjc -p [myNamespace] [myFile].xsd

Comment: You should probably post more of your compilation error message, together with the generated class (where you say your inner class is) and the code the compiler complains about.